# How to output a 2d list from list and integers

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function that takes an input list and two integers as parameters, the function should then return a two-dimensional list with the rows and columns of the list being specified by the two input integers. e.g. if the input list is `[8, 2, 9, 4, 1, 6, 7, 8, 7, 10]` and the two integers are 2 and 3 then the function should return `[[8, 2, 9],[4, 1, 6]]`

```
def one_to_2D(some_list, r, c):
    output = []

    for a in range(0, r):
        my_list = some_list[0:c]
        some_list.reverse()
        for k in range(0,r):
            some_list.pop()
        some_list.reverse()
        output.append(my_list)

    return output

some_list = [8, 2, 9, 4, 1, 6, 7, 8, 7, 10]
print(one_to_2D(some_list, 2, 3))
```

Comment: I found the problem despite not being told what it was: You need to change `for k in range(0,r):` to `for k in range(0,c):`.

Comment: Why are you reversing the list twice just to remove all the values?

Comment: Hi, sorry im not very good at this. the reason I reverse the list is because I want the output to contain the first integers of the list e.g. if the input is 2,3 then I would like the output to be [[8,2,9],[4,1,6]] because those are the first 6 integers in my input list.

Comment: @Pi-thon, what happens when c is too big?

Comment: if the number of elements in the input list is larger than r*c then ignore the extra elements. If the number of elements in the input list is less than r*c then fill the two dimensional list with the keyword None.

Comment: That is quite important as every answer is currently not doing that

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution for you:

```
def one_to_2D(some_list, r, c):
    return [[some_list[j] for j in range(c*i, c*(i+1))] for i in range(r)]
```

Examples:

```
In [3]: one_to_2D([8, 2, 9, 4, 1, 6, 7, 8, 7, 10], 2, 3)
Out[3]: [[8, 2, 9], [4, 1, 6]]

In [4]: one_to_2D([8, 2, 9, 4, 1, 6, 7, 8, 7, 10], 3, 3)
Out[4]: [[8, 2, 9], [4, 1, 6], [7, 8, 7]]

In [5]: one_to_2D([8, 2, 9, 4, 1, 6, 7, 8, 7, 10], 2, 2)
Out[5]: [[8, 2], [9, 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution with a for loop and Python's slice notation:

```
def one_to_2D(some_list, r, c):
    result = []
    for i in range(1, r+1):
        result.append(some_list[c*(i-1):c*i])
    return result

print(one_to_2D([8, 2, 9, 4, 1, 6, 7, 8, 7, 10], 2, 3))
```

Output:

```
[[8, 2, 9], [4, 1, 6]]
```

Comment: Thank you, this was just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension, it is usually faster than the extended for loop version:

```
def one_to_2D(some_list, r, c):
    return [some_list[i:i+c] for i in range(0, len(some_list), c][:r]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the product of your row and column integers is equal to the length of the list then you can convert the list to a numpy array and reshape it:

```
import numpy as np
>>> list = [8, 2, 9, 4, 1, 6, 7, 8, 7, 10]
>>> np.array(list).reshape(5, 2)
array([[ 8,  2],
   [ 9,  4],
   [ 1,  6],
   [ 7,  8],
   [ 7, 10]])
```

In your example, the integers you chose were 2, 3 which is a smaller matrix than the length of the list. You could write a simple function that slices the list to fit the dimensions of your matrix:

```
def one_to_2D(arr, r, c):
    if len(arr) > r * c:
        new_arr = arr[:-(len(arr)-r*c)]
        return np.array(new_arr).reshape(r, c)
    elif len(arr) < r * c:
        print 'list length less than r x c'
    else:
        return np.array(arr).reshape(r,c)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.islice` calling `iter` on the list:

```
from itertools import islice
def one_to_2D(some_list, r, c):
    it = iter(some_list)
    return [list(islice(it, c)) for _ in range(r)]
```

Output:

```
In [15]: (one_to_2D(some_list, 2, 3)
   ....: )
Out[15]: [[8, 2, 9], [4, 1, 6]]

In [16]: (one_to_2D(some_list, 2, 2))
Out[16]: [[8, 2], [9, 4]]

In [17]: (one_to_2D(some_list, 2, 4))
Out[17]: [[8, 2, 9, 4], [1, 6, 7, 8]]
```

Based on *if the number of elements in the input list is larger than rc then ignore the extra elements. If the number of elements in the input list is less than r times c then fill the two dimensional list with the keyword None*, you need to pad with None:

```
def one_to_2D(some_list, r, c):
    if r * c > len(some_list):
        some_list.extend([None] * (r * c - len(some_list)) )
    it = iter(some_list)
    return [list(islice(it, c)) for _ in range(r)]
```

Output:

```
In [19]: (one_to_2D(some_list, 2, 4))
Out[19]: [[8, 2, 9, 4], [1, 6, 7, 8]]

In [20]: (one_to_2D(some_list, 2, 6))
Out[20]: [[8, 2, 9, 4, 1, 6], [7, 8, 7, 10, None, None]]
```

If you have to use a regular loop:

```
def one_to_2D(some_list, r, c):
    if r * c > len(some_list):
        some_list.extend([None] * (r * c - len(some_list)))
    l = []
    for i in range(0, r * c, c):
        l.append(some_list[i:i + c])
    return l
```

Comment: No worries, you can use whatever means you wan to create the list, `[some_list[i:i+c] for i in range(0, r*c, c)]` or a regular loop, the important part is making sure you pad the values on the end

Answer (score 0):

```
In [10]: reshaped = [some_list[i:i+c] for i in range(0,r*c, c)]
[[8, 2, 9], [4, 1, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Function inputs  : a list and two integers --> r, c
# Function output  : a 2D_list by r*c shape

def one_to_2D(some_list, r, c):
    # If the number of elements in the input list
    # is larger than rc then ignore the extra elements.
    # If the number of elements in the input list
    # is less than rc then fill the two dimensional list
    # with the keyword None, we need to pad with None:
    if r*c > len(some_list):
        some_list.extend([None] * (r*c - len(some_list)))
    #print (some_list)

    # This list will contains 
    # the number of r in the list elements.
    # It then extends these elements to the _2D_list
    # after completing the internal loop once.
    result = []

    # Will contain those items that extended into _2D_list from result
    _2D_list = [] 

    for i in range(r):  # 0 <= i < r
        for j in range(i*c, (i+1)*c):
            # i*c <= j < (i+1)*c
            ## i == 0 ===> 0  <= j < c
            ## i == 1 ===> c  <= j < 2c
            ## i == 2 ===> 2c <= j < 3c
            ## ...
            ## ...
            ## i == r ===> break
            result.append(some_list[j])
        _2D_list.extend([result])
        result = []
        # After completing one step of the inner loop,
        # the result items must be deleted by result = [].
        # Because otherwise they will go to the exit(out).

    return _2D_list

    # This function simply with list comprehension ...
    #return [[some_list[j] for j in range(c*i, c*(i+1))] for i in range(r)]

##########################################################
##### Main Program  #####
some_list = [8, 2, 9, 4, 5]
print (one_to_2D(some_list, 3, 4))
```

Comment: Everything is explained within the program.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps:

```
def one_to_2D(some_list, r, c):

    output = []
    if r*c > len(some_list):
        return None

    for i in range(r):
        tl = []
        for j in range(c):
            tl.append(some_list[i*c+j])
        output.append(tl)

    return output

some_list = [8, 2, 9, 4, 1, 6, 7, 8, 7, 10]
print(one_to_2D(some_list, 2, 3))
```